# бьет ошибку при создании APK....java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: java, android

бьет ошибку при создании APK....

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   org/json/simple/ItemList.class

причем только при создании APK со своим ключом....Во всех остальных случаях все компилиться и на вирт.машину и на телефон

CleanBuilding И Rebuild делала, не помогает...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "calculation.material.*********"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 23
        versionName "3.0.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.9'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
    compile 'me.srodrigo:androidhintspinner:1.0.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.jaeger.ninegridimageview:library:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
    compile 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.38'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'org.apache.clerezza.ext:org.json.simple:0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: build.gradle показывайте - похоже на дубликаты в зависимостях

Comment: В папке `libs` ничего забытого нет случайно?

Comment: нету такой папки

Comment: Тогда это `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` закомментируйте и повторите еще раз.

Comment: не помогло! =(((